# Get mysql result according to table priority

Tags: mysql, join, sql-like

In my website, I would like to implement a `live data search`. I have two tables `table_a` and `table_b`.

`table_a` has the main data, and `table_b` has the sub data which is referred from `table_a`.

I am getting the result. But the join gives importance to `table_b` data.

I would like to get the data as

**1. If `table_a` has the specific result, then show that with its corresponding `table_b` data.**

2. If `table_a` does not have the value, then show `table_b` data if any

The query which I am executing now is

```
SELECT
    a.aname,
    b.bname
FROM 
    table_a AS a
JOIN table_b AS b ON b.a_id_fk = a.a_id
WHERE
    (a.a_name LIKE '%a%' OR b.b_name LIKE '%a%')
```

I know this will not take result according to my need.

Is there any way to do this with a single query?

Any help will be appreciated.. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

**If table_a does not have the value, then show table_b data if any**

If i understand correctly

```
SELECT
   case when a_id is null then  b.bname else  a.aname end as name,

FROM 
   table_b AS b left join table_a AS a
 ON b.a_id_fk = a.a_id
WHERE
    (a.a_name LIKE '%a%' OR b.b_name LIKE '%a%')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not exactly your point. I may have values in both `table_a` and `table_b`. But I need to show the value in `table_a` as it has first priority